# Extracting the first letter of each word in a string in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I'm trying to extract the first letter of each word that is present in a Hive column. For example:
One Two Three should return OTT in the new column

I tried to make use of the `regexp_extract` function in the following way:

`Select regexp_extract(concat(" ", cname_cleaned), '\\s[a-zA-Z]{1}', 0)`

where `cname_cleaned` is the column name I want to work with. I've concatenated a space before the word so that the first word can also be included in the regex pattern. The output is as follows:

`One Two Three` -> `O`

The query gives me the first match. Is there a way to extract all matches together.

Comment: you mx single and double quores, please show the hava code and use only the one that works

Comment: A mix of single and double quotes works fine on Hive. I am running the query on hive itself